# How can I analyse each letter in a string and pair it with an input?

Tags: python, string, input

I'm trying to set it up in a way where I can compare thier "input letter" with the "actual letter" and make an if statement if they get it right or wrong.

I'm also gonna have to figure out how to setup this code in a way where "Number of questions asked= to the number of letters" .

```
import random

#hangman code

#lift of wrds
wrds= ["cat", "dog"]

rW=(random.choice((wrds)))
print (rW)

lWrd= len(rW)

wordq= input ("Would you like to play hang-man? ")

if wordq=="yes":
  print ("Your word has", lWrd, "letters" )
  fl= input("what do u think the letter is? ")
  if fl ==  rW[0]:
    print ("Your right")
```

Comment: I'm afraid you have a long way to go.. You can use `if fl in rw:` to determine if the letter is in the word at all.  You'll then need to track which letters have been played.  And usually, instead of saying "your word has N letters", you display something like "- - -" with one dash for each letter.  As they guess letters, you fill them in.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
i = 0
while i < len(word):
    x = input("guess letter")
    if x == word[i]:
        print("youre right")
        i+=1
    else:
        print("oops try again")
```

Comment: thanks alot for your help